# fields.Selection based on values of "self" is empty

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

```py
labelSelect = fields.Selection(selection='checkLine',string='Selection')


@api.multi                                  
def checkLine(self):                        
    ar = []                                 
    for order in self:                                     
        ar.append(('test',str(order.name)))                       
    return ar
```

I added field in inherited class of `sale.order` "labelSelect" and the function "checkLine" returns array, which should be the value of Selection field.

Any idea why it doesn't work and every order has no option for selection?

When I replace `for order in self` with `for order in self.env['sale.order'].search([])` just for test, it works, and all orders are visible in Selection field but I want to show different value for different orders based on `self`.

Comment: So it looks like self is empty. Cant you use simple char field? Or reference?

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Self is not empty because before 'return ar' I've added --_logger.info(ar) and it shows correct array. Yeah, it seems that I'd need to use another workaround but firstly I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong in this function.

Comment: Can you paste a content of ar variable?

Comment: [('test', 'ERP503')]  (this is what I see as a result of _logger.info(ar)

Comment: I checked it. Unfortunately field selection seems to be model related. Dynamic domain could be a solution, but it doesn't work with selection field. Try to use a field related instead.

Comment: Cool, thank you so much for your effort.